# Using JMX to read ejb manifest jar and ejb-jar.xml in ejb jar inside ear

Tags: java, weblogic, ejb, jmx

I have an ear deployed on weblogic console. I need to check contents of manifest file and ejb-jar.xml of a jar that is present in the deployed ear.

Currently I am using the code below to access jar inside ear deployed :

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable(5);
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,
url);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
mBeanHome = (MBeanHome)ctx.lookup(MBeanHome.ADMIN_JNDI_NAME);

String type = "EJBComponentRuntime"; 
Set beans = mBeanHome.getMBeansByType(type); 



try{
for(Iterator it=beans.iterator();it.hasNext();)
{ 
EJBComponentRuntimeMBean rt = (EJBComponentRuntimeMBean)it.next(); 

if(rt.getParent().getName().equals("xxx")){
System.out.println(rt.getName());
l.add(rt.getName());
```

Here `xxx` is the ear. Now I need to get inside the jar (represented) by variable "`rt`" and access its manifest file,`ejb-jar.xml`

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? I understand we can access manifest files using `jarinputstream`. However how do i get that stream?

regards
Sameer

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jarfile.jar/META-INF/ejb-jar.xml");
```

where jarfile.jar that is present in ear.